# What function does the chip in a Deutschlandticket have?

Tags: germany, public-transport, deutschlandticket

The Deutschlandticket now exists in a version with an integrated chip. What function does this chip actually have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chip contains a digital representation of the ticket and some information about the ticket owner. According to VDV eTicket Service, the chip contains the following information:

- Name
- Gender
- Date of birth
- smart card number and its period of validity
- the ticket itself including at least ticket type, issuing operator, period of validity and ticket number

This data can be used by staff to verify that the ticket is valid (inside period of validity, issued by an authorized issuer, not cancelled, smart card not marked as lost/stolen) and that the card holder is entitled to use the ticket saved on the card.

You can check the data saved on the chip with the [eTicket app](https://sasse-solutions.de/eticket-app)

Answer (score 8):

The chip cards are actually made according to the [eTicket Deutschland](https://www.eticket-deutschland.de/en/eticket/) standard, so they can be used where the standard is used

[image]

Comment: Mine is provided by VRN vrn.de .

Comment: All of the mentioned operators offer the D-Ticket on a smart card. You can explicitely select "Chipkarte" when ordering from BVG and Mainzer Mobilität. bodo asks you to create an account before registering, but mentions on its website that they offer the D-Ticket on a smart card. Furthermore there are several operators offering the D-Ticket on a smart card which haven't been mentioned, like MVG in Munich or KVB in Cologne. 
It might be sensible to just remove the paragraph about availability as it is likely to be largely incomplete.

Comment: @Inconspicuousseagull Indeed, removed